# How can the Almighty purify himself?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, theology, water

The Gemara discusses something of the following question:

How can the Almighty purify himself, His Presence can never be contained in any body of water, so how can He ever properly emerge Himself?

Comment: Hi -- your question would be stronger if you included citations to the source which makes the claim about which you ask.

Comment: It would also help to explain what it would mean for God to be impure?

Comment: If you are talking about G-d at His essence, G-d transcends tumah and tahara. If you are referring to the name of G-d usually referred to by the name Almighty, just like we have waters for purification below, so too there are waters for purification above. That concept is derived from the doubling letters of the Aleph-Beit.

Comment: You don't seem to be asking anything here. You state what the G'mara asks. What is _your_ question?

Answer (score 2):

**Sanhedrin 39a**

> אמר ליה ההוא מינא לרבי אבהו אלהיכם כהן הוא דכתיב ויקחו לי תרומה כי קבריה למשה במאי טביל וכי תימא במיא והכתיב מי מדד בשעלו
> מים אמר ליה בנורא טביל דכתיב כי הנה ה׳ באש יבוא ומי סלקא טבילותא בנורא אמר ליה אדרבה עיקר טבילותא בנורא הוא דכתיב וכל אשר לא יבא באש תעבירו במים
>
> A certain Min said to R. Abbahu: Your God is a priest, since it is written, That they take for me Terumah [wave offering]. Now, when He had buried Moses, wherein did He bathe [after contact with the corpse]? Should you reply, ‘In water: is it not written, Who hath measured the waters in the hollow of His hand? — ‘He bathed in fire,’ he answered, ‘for it is written, Behold the Lord will come in fire.’   ‘Is then purification by fire effective?’ ‘On the contrary,’ he replied, ‘bathing [for purposes of purification] should essentially be in fire, for it is written, And all that abideth not the fire ye shall make to go through the water.’
>
> (Soncino translation)

Comment: I believe you might be misunderstanding the Gemara. The question of the Min was a ludicrous question since obviously Hashem transcends tumah and taharah. He therefore responded with a ludicrous answer...

Comment: @fartgeek I didn't say whether the answer represents the actual reality or not. I merely provided the answer that was given when someone asked this question to a Talmudic rabbi.

Comment: Beautiful comment.  Who can know whether the answer in the Gemara represents the actual reality or not?

Comment: The Almighty is entitled to engage in self-purification if He so chooses to do so, or perhaps the entire basis of the question is unfounded. I really am not sure about the best answer to these questions.

Comment: The psalm says, “During the great flood, Hashem sat, and He sits King of the world.” I get the impression that by making the world Tahor through His instigation of this great flood, He actually increased the value of His being King over the entire world, just as He increased the value of Man to be ruler over all of the animals.

Comment: Also if you look at the history, the time line, of Comet Hale-Bopp, you see that the last time this comet appeared was just before that great flood, so the modern appearance of this same comet seems to suggest a flood of fire also as a form of purification to the world this time around.  I believe that this is the suggestion that we find in Tikun Hazohar 19.

Comment: So in away you could say that by making a Mikve of Fire this time around He will be purifying His own role as King of the World.